# Resizing Twinned axis for plotting of different type of data versus a common parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data. It is recorded as different parameters against a common parameter. For example, say time on X Axis and Temperature, Wind Speed etc. on Y Axis.

I have been using origin to do my plotting. In origin, such manipulations are carried out by use of Layers. Each axis on different layers can share X or Y axis from the host. And it can be resized so that the plot is drawn on some percentage of actual area. Please see the attached sketch.

I am trying to achieve something similar in python to shift to open-source. After some reading, I found out **twinx()** and **twiny()** are two axes functions that can clone/share an axis. Spines can be moved as required through **spine['pos'].set_position()**.

My problem is that, although X axis is shared, I can not individually resize the Y axis of individual parameters. On using set_position, whole figure changes. Request the community for a solution. I am including a snippet of representative code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,11))
host = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.7,0.8])
host.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])

parm1 = host.twinx()
#parm1.set_position([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.5]) #this doesn't work
parm1.spines['right'].set_position(('axes',1.1))
..
..
```

[image: A representative sketch]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an existing function in matplotlib that can do what you want in one call. However, with a little bit of work, you can achieve something like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
bx.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
bx.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
bx.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
bx.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Cosine')
bx.set_ylabel('Sine')
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), color='xkcd:avocado', linestyle='dashdot', linewidth=3)
bx.plot(x, np.sin(x), color='xkcd:purple', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thak you for your reply. One possibility I found is to use twinx() (as shown in twinx() demo) to create multiple plots, then scale individual plot y axes to adjust position. Is there an option to partially hide ticks and spines?

Comment: @TsarS I am sorry, I do not quite get your comment. Is my answer satisfying? If no, how would you like it changed? If you want to use `twinx`, I do not see how you can achieve something similar to the plot above. About hiding ticks and spines, yes, it is possible, it is exactly what I do in my answer...

Comment: Apologies. In my representation picture, the host Y axis will also be used to plot. With compacted individual subplots, i will not be able to overlay another, i think. But half of what I am trying to achieve can be done with your method too. The method, that i mentioned in the comment, is proving a little complicated for me to demonstrate. i will post it when I  get it working, for clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by "I will not be able to overlay another"?

Comment: @TsarS Have you made any progress?

Comment: I was able to do what I intended. I had to use set_bounds() method for spines. Although achievable, it needs a lot of backend calculation for properly dividing various parameters to fit neatly on the host grid. I am yet to adopt this method for multiple variables to test it.